# bash - imapsync: BAD CR sent without LF

Tags: bash

I have wrote script for massive transfer in imapsync:

```
#!/bin/sh
echo
{ while IFS=';' read  u1 p1 u2 p2; do
        echo "==== Starting transfer for $u2 ===="
        imapsync \
                --host1 "src.host.com" --user1 "$u1" --password1 "$p1" \
                    --noauthmd5 \
                    --sep1 "." --prefix1 "" \
                --host2 "desc.host.com" --user2 "$u2" --password2 "$p2" \
                    --sep2 "." --prefix2 "" \
                --folder "INBOX" \
                > ./logs/"$u1".log
        echo "==== Ended transfer for $u2 ===="
done ; } < cred.txt
```

And that's how looks `cred.txt`

```
src@email.com;password!;dest@email.com;3kXxFQBm7u
(empty line)
```

Now, when I trying to run this script, I'm getting:

```
==== Starting transfer for dest@email.com ====
2 BAD CR sent without LF
        ...propagated at /usr/bin/imapsync line 759.
==== Ended transfer for dest@email.com ====
```

but if I'm enter second password staticaly (code will looks like below) - it's working, why?

```
#!/bin/sh
echo
{ while IFS=';' read  u1 p1 u2 p2; do
        echo "==== Starting transfer for $u2 ===="
        imapsync \
                --host1 "src.host.com" --user1 "$u1" --password1 "$p1" \
                    --noauthmd5 \
                    --sep1 "." --prefix1 "" \
                --host2 "desc.host.com" --user2 "$u2" --password2 "3kXxFQBm7u" \
                    --sep2 "." --prefix2 "" \
                --folder "INBOX" \
                > ./logs/"$u1".log
        echo "==== Ended transfer for $u2 ===="
done ; } < cred.txt
```

Comment: I'll bet anything `cred.txt` has Windows CRLF line breaks, fix it with `dos2unix`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the problem is only with the password at the end of the line, your file probably has CRLF line breaks because it was created on a Windows system. Fix it with

```
dos2unix cred.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

In case you are not having `dos2unix` in your system and you are not root too then you could use following commands to remove these carriage characters on same too:

```
tr -d '\r' < Input_file > temp_file && mv temp_file Input_file
OR
awk '{gsub(/\r/,"")} 1' Input_file > temp_file && mv temp_file Input_file
```

Answer (score 0):

Add an extra ; at the end of each line in cred.txt like this:

```
src@email.com;password!;dest@email.com;3kXxFQBm7u;
```